# package javax.servlet.annotation does not exist while using jboss

Tags: java, jsp, maven, servlets

I am using Jboss 7.

I added a servlet to my project.

I have added the `servlet-api.jar` in my library

I have added dependency for `servlet-api.jar` in my pom.xml as

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>${version}</version>
</dependency>
```

However, I still get error

package javax.servlet.annotation does not exist when i do a maven -> install

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are missing `javax.` in your dependency at `<artifactId>`. And do remember if you want to use annotation, your servlet version should be `>3.0`. Here is dependency for `servlet 3.1`.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
   </dependency>
```

Comment: I don't see version 3.1.0 here:   https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api    in fact, 2.5 is the latest stable...

Comment: As mentioned on link you provided the artifact is moved to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api